# Python, Pandas: Datframe - keep, not drop columns

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning,

the dataframes I am working with always (100%) contain four certain columns, but the rest of them varies! Is there a way to keep only certain columns and not dropping them? Right now I'm using this code to execute...

```
df = df.drop(["column_a", "column_b", "column_c", axis=1)
```

...but everytime the amount of columns changed I have to adjust my code.

Thanks and have a great weekend!

Comment: If there a specific pattern in the columns to keep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df = df[['col_to_keep_1', 'col_to_keep_2', 'col_to_keep_3', 'col_to_keep_4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete all columns except some columns, you could use this:

```
df = df.loc[:, ['a','b']]
```

Where `df['a']` and `df['b']` are the columns to keep.